# JavaScript is enabled in opera browser but portail azure doesnt work

Tags: javascript, azure

[image]I have enabled javaScript in the settings[image]
now when I access portail azure it alwways says that javaScript is disabled

I have tried with other browsers like chrome and edge , its the same , is it a problem in my own machine ? I even tried to wipe cache and browsing data and its still not working !

Comment: Please provide more details on what you are trying to achieve and where you are facing the issue along with the screenshots of errors if you are getting any.

Comment: Sure ! i have included two screenshots in the description

Comment: Update chrome and edge to latest version and try to access Azure portal as mentioned in [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-supported-browsers-devices#recommended-browsers).

Comment: Is it working? Are you able to access portal @Mohamed?

Comment: it works fine ! I updated chrome to latest version and now its working , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comments as answer:

**You are not able to access Azure portal in Opera browser because it is not allowed to use in Opera.**

As mentioned in the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-supported-browsers-devices#recommended-browsers),
Azure portal supports in only few browsers:

- Latest version of Microsoft Edge
- Latest version of Google Chrome
- Latest version of Firefox and
- Latest version of Safari only in ***Mac os***.

> I have tried with other browsers like chrome and edge , its the same , is it a problem in my own machine ? I even tried to wipe cache and browsing data and its still not working !

- **Update your Chrome/Edge** to its **latest versions**.
- Or **Uninstall Chrome/Edge** and **install** it again, you will be able to access Azure Portal.

[image]